# Can't seem to get mod_rewrite to behave the way I need it to

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm dealing with a server that has mod_rewrite enabled but I can't seem to get any rewrites to work except one...

The following works

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule (.*) /test.php [R=301,L]
```

But obviously creates an endless loop back to test.php. So if I type website.com/something, it's being redirected to test.php which is then redirected to itself endlessly.

However, something like this isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule /something.html /something.php [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add base and supply base symbol (^) to rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^something.html /something.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /test.php [L] #this rule must not issue 301 redirect
```